# Fsolve, replicating code from matlab, answer not matching because of Fsolve requirements

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, python-requests, wxpython, mathematical-optimization

It will be very helpful if I can get a help,  I am stuck in this problem for a long time. TIA

My function is returning 2 arrays, 6 by 6 and 6 by 1 , and the starting point for solving has the size of 6 by 1, as the output has to be scalar or 1d ,I have converted the 2 output arrays into one with size of (42,1) and I have reshaped the size of the starting point to (42,1) , I have tried by adding additional zeros, repeating the original starting point 7 times, to increase the size from (6,1) to size (42,1) .
Because of this,  I am not getting the desired result from the  fsolve, I was replicating the code from matlab to python and in matlab fsolve was giving right answer and it was working fine with output as 2 arrays of(6,6) and (6,1) and starting point for solving as (6,1)

Comment: Can you please post your code in your question as a code block (paste it in, select it, click the `{ }` button) and give us an example of your inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: Hi,  I will post the code tomorrow, the code is in my office PC

Comment: I have posted the question again,  this time I have posted the matlab as well as python code, any help would be helpful